How can I prevent window titles from overlapping in a Maui app with shell navigation and modals?
I'm developing a Maui app with shell navigation and modals, and I'm encountering an issue with overlapping window titles. When navigating from the main page to another page using shell navigation, a back button appears, causing the window title to shift slightly to the right. However, when I push a modal on that page, the window title on the modal page remains in its original position. This results in both window titles overlapping and creating a visually awkward effect.
I've attached images for reference
MainPage:

Navigated to another page using shell navigation:

Pushed Modal Page:

Any insights, code snippets, or suggestions would be immensely helpful. Thank you!

For Shell Navigation, you can use GoToAsync method to perform navigation:
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//pageroute");

And for the back button, you can add it to the targeted Page to remove or hide it:
<Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
    <BackButtonBehavior IsVisible="False" IsEnabled="False" />
</Shell.BackButtonBehavior>

Or use Pushed Modal Page(PushModalAsync) as you said still work in terms of Naviagtion, but has some unwanted effect. Let's use Shell.Current.GoToAsync in the first priority.
